# How to provide more than one overrides for one virtual function

Tags: c++, polymorphism, overriding

I have the following classes :

```
class A {
};

class B : public A {
};

class P     {
private:
 std::list<A*> l
protected:
 virtual void DoIt(A* a) = 0;
public:
 void WorkerThread() { for (it=l.begin(); it!=l.end(); it++) DoIt(*it); }
};

class Q : public P
{
protected:
 void DoIt(A* a) { print("false"); }
 void DoIt(B* b) { print("true"); }
};
```

Unfortunately, DoIt(B* b) will never get called. 
DoIt(A* a) will always be called even if I add B objects to the list.

What can I do to make DoIt(B* b) called ?
Is it possible to achieve this if B does not know Q ?
Is it possible to achieve this if without dynamic cast ?

Thank you

Comment: How can both DoIt methods exist in Q without being rejected as ambiguous?

Comment: @David - because they're not.

Comment: Also, the STL containers are not really built to be inherited from (as P does, above).  Use composition instead.

Comment: @Noah So if you have an object b, of type B, and pa, a pointer to A you can't write pa = &b?

Comment: @David - you most certainly can.  The function is not ambiguous because the compiler is required to call the overload that most closely matches the static type of the parameters.  Thus it can quite easily tell when DoIt(A*) should be called and when DoIt(B*) should be called.  DoIt(B*) should be called any time it CAN be.

Comment: @David - actually, more correctly, they are not ambiguous in the class they are created in.  Ambiguity rarely occurs there.  There are situations though in which it COULD be ambiguous, but that happens at call site based on types.  With the posted types there can be none.  If B and A where both base classes (didn't inherit from each other) and C derived from them though...and you called it with a C*...then you'd have an ambiguity problem.

Comment: @Noah This sucks! It's real blow your legs off territory!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, nobody's really directly answered your question (well, heavyd tried) so I will.  Some other "answers" here are actually more helpful for fixing your problem though.

The issue is that void DoIt(B*) is NOT an override of the virtual function DoIt(A*).  It's an *overload*.  There's a HUGE difference.

When you say that DoIt(B*) is not called when you pass a B* I have to assume that you're holding references or pointers to you Q through a pointer to something higher up the higherarchy.  In those cases the static name resolution only finds DoIt(A*) and since B* is-a A* it gets upcasted and that's the version that gets called.  Since it is virtual the override in Q is what gets called.

If you had a pointer to Q as a pointer to Q though, and called DoIt with a B* the DoIt(B*) function should get called.  At this point, double dispatch is not needed and is not used.

You need double dispatch when you have two abstract types and a function that must behave differently based on the concrete types of both abstractions.  This is what you're attempting to do when you call DoIt with B on Q at a higher level than static naming provides.  There are too many methods that answer different needs to be able to suggest one solution over another in your case, don't really know what you're trying to solve.  In fact, you might not even need it!  A better approach for you might be to implement DoIt(B*) as a virtual function in the top of your higherarchy.

I would suggest that you get Andre Alexandrescu's book, Modern C++ Design, and look it over.  He explains a pretty darn cool visitor implementation as well as a multiple dispatch mechanism that scales.  Don't stop there though, there's other great implementations that can answer the question differently.

Good luck.

Comment: Many thanks for all your comments. In my case, you can imagine that A and B are events, P is an event bus and Q is an event processor. So, it is not possible that P declares a virtual DoIt for every possible event.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a double dispatch mechanism that is not built into the language. There are different approaches on how this can be implemented based on the visitor pattern. Google for double-dispatch in C++. Note that this is a patch and not easily extended to big hierarchies:

```
struct visitor;
struct A {
   virtual void accept( visitor& v ) { v(*this); }
};
struct B {
   virtual void accept( visitor& v ) { v(*this); }
}; 
struct visitor {
   virtual void operator()( A& ) = 0;
   virtual void operator()( B& ) = 0; 
};
struct myvisitor : visitor {
   void operator( A& ) { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; }
   void operator( B& ) { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; }
};
int main() {
   std::vector<A*> data = ...
   myvisitor v;
   for ( std::vector<A*>::iterator it = data.begin(), end = data.end(); it != end; ++it )
   {
      (*it)->accept( v );
   }
}
```

The usual mechanism will be used and `accept` will be dispatched to the final overrider of the method, which in turn will call the visitor method. Now, at that point, the static type of the argument to the visitor `operator()` *is* in fact the actual type that you want to call the function with.

Comment: one precision as the OP does not seem clear on override/overload, this solution requires the base class (`visitor`) to provide virtual methods for all the concrete types. One cannot derive from `visitor` and add another *overload* of `operator()`

Comment: Thanks. I think this is want I need.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is want I need. The constraint that the base visitor class has to know every types (A, B, ...) is probably acceptable in my case. Anyway I will check other solutions mentionned in this post.

Answer (score 1):

`DoIt(B* b)` will never get called because you are never passing in objects of type B*, every time you call `DoIt`, at least in the given code, you are passing in objects of type `A*`.

Consider the situation where the override of `Doit(A* a)` did not exist.  Your current code would not compile because it the compiler cannot implicitly cast an object of type `A*` to `B*`.

Comment: This is almost certainly not the case.  It would be pretty silly for someone to pass in objects of type A* and expect the B* version to get called.  What they probably are expecting is that the B* *overload* actually *overrides* the A* version and that doesn't work in C++.

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting the behaviour to be if someone passes in an A* but the underlying type is really a B?

You might be looking for something like this:

```
class A
{
public:
  virtual ~A() {}
  virtual bool isB() const { return false; }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
  bool isB() const { return true; }
};

void Q::DoIt( A* a )
{
   print( a->isB() ? "true" : "false" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is known as [multiple dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) and won't work in C++ because function overloading is static. Take a look at the wikipedia article for some possible work arounds.

For example, if you don't want the logic for the `DoIt` functionality in the `A` and `B` classes themselves as a virtual function then you could use the `dynamic_cast` method:

```
class A {
};

class B : public A {
};

class P : protected std::list<A*>
{
protected:
 virtual void DoIt(A* a) = 0;
public:
 void WorkerThread() { for (it=begin(); it!=end(); it++) DoIt(*it); }
};

class Q : public P
{
protected:
 void DoIt(A* a) {
  if(B *b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a)) {
   // It's a B*, you can "use" b here
   print("true");
  } else {
   // It's an A*
   print("false");
  }
 }
};
```

Comment: -1 -> double dispatch is quite common in C++.  Multiple too.  There's numerous approaches.

Comment: @Noah: Yes, commonly used through various methods. But not supported natively by the language specification like he's attempting.

Comment: @Matthieu - The OP did and it has been mentioned that it was a bad idea.  You're being rather twitish harping on it in answers.

Comment: @Noah: I expect an OP not to be C++ savvy, but I expect an answer to promote good code, I'll remove my vote (and comments) once the answers have been edited.

Comment: I also thought to the dynamic cast solution that's why I asked in my post if it was possible to do it without dynamic cast.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for multiple dispatch or multimethods. Wikipedia has a nice example for c++; link [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch#C.2B.2B).